# Challenge on mapping on Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a data manipulation project - where I have to map through an array of arrays and export a single string of all possibilities within these arrays.

For example:

```
const array = [
    [{id: 1}, {id: 2}], [{id: "a"}, {id: "b"}], [{id: "string"}]
]
```

Expected output is to have:

```
const newArray = ["1_a_string", "2_a_string", "1_b_string", "2_b_string"]
```

I'm having challenges in having all permutations knowing:

1. I don't know the lenght of initial array
2. I don't know the lenght of the array inside the initial array.

Appreciate if anyone can guide me to the right path to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: *I'm having challenges* - I don't see you actually trying anything so far. Show us what you tried so far, and give a proper explanation of what the problem with it was.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this and you can manipulate this function as your requirement . that means if you want concated string something like that..

```
function print(arr)
{
    let n = arr.length;
     
    let indices = new Array(n);
   
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        indices[i] = 0;
     
    while (true)
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
            document.write(
            arr[i][indices[i]].id + " ");
          
        document.write("<br>");
        let next = n - 1;
        while (next >= 0 && (indices[next] + 1 >=
                                 arr[next].length))
            next--;
         
        if (next < 0)
            return;
         
        indices[next]++;
         
        for(let i = next + 1; i < n; i++)
            indices[i] = 0;
    }
}
 
// Driver code
 

const array = [
    [{id: 1}, {id: 2}], [{id: "a"}, {id: "b"}], [{id: "string"}]
]

 
print(array);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/qBpWpqV) is codepan link